# How to access linkedin from python command

Tags: python, command, linkedin-api

I want to access my linkedin account from command prompt and then i wanted to send mails from my account using command.
Also, I need the delivery reports of the mails.
Can anyone knows how can use that?

Comment: Stop writing tags in titles please.

Comment: ok sure will not do that from now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Member to Member API will return a 2xx status code if your message is accepted by LinkedIn. And a 4xx status code if there's an error.

This means the message was put into the LinkedIn system, not that it has been opened, read, emailed, etc. You cannot get that via the API.

Comment: ok but it means that 2xx status code is delivery reports for messages sent. if one will be paid member, will he be able to send messages to the one who is not in his connect list?

Comment: You need to use InMail (http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=about_inmail). But there is no InMail API yet.

Comment: ohh...it means the peoples who are using python api for linkedin sends bulk messages only to the people they know?

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search gives you:

http://code.google.com/p/python-linkedin/

Comment: I have already gone through that but it dont speak about delivery reports of the mail sent.